# How do I go about recovering from the ordeal of an employment scam?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, india

I have been a victim of employment scam. Back when I was looking for work after graduation (was desperate because of no internship and poor grades), I joined a well-known Indian IT Services company which offered a paid training program that provided a temporary contract job with minimum wages (after training).

Looking back I am sure I did not do my research and due diligence. It was a lack of experience or [insert adjective] that made me vulnerable to the deception.

So this job is your typical scam where they give whatever reasons they feel to not employ you after some period. For me, I was verbally given ridiculous reasons that I don't want to delve into.

This whole situation has left me scarred for life! I am too shocked I can not describe in words.

So my question is how do I cope with this inhumane treatment by a big IT Co? If you are an employer how much impact does it have in your considering my candidature?

Also, are there some reasons that I can give easily about this job when asked about more than the regular questions (like what did you not like about your previous job?) that will not raise eyebrows?

Comment: I'm trying to find the question in this. Are you looking for advice about how to find another job even though you are upset and hurt by what happened with this one?

Comment: I have edited it. My main question is regarding employability. I will be making more edits as I think it still reeks of emotions.

Comment: Which country this happened?

Comment: Why do you think this was a scam? Why don't you think it was anything but a temporary contract that ran to its conclusion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you need to present the bare facts when applying for your next job:

- You graduated
- You did a training course
- You worked a temporary contract for well-known IT services company *x*
- That temporary contract has now concluded and you are looking for full-time work

Don't be volunteering information like the fact that you were led to believe the temporary contract would lead to a full-time job, nor that you were given ridiculous reasons for that not happening, nor that you consider the training and job to have been a scam. It was a temp contract, it ended, you are now looking for a new position.

You need to talk about it like it was just a regular temporary contract. Talk about the work you did. Talk about what you learned. If you're asked "what did you not like about your previous job?" don't bad-mouth the company. Talk about something technical and emotionally neutral, best of all if it's something you can parlay into a positive for the job you're applying for, e.g. "they used tools *a* and *b*, I think *c* and *d* are more effective", when you know the company you're interviewing at uses *c* and/or *d*.

Basically, no potential employer wants to hear you complain about your previous employer. Even if they richly deserve it, no good will come of it. If you need to unload about the bad experience, do it over beers with your friends, not in a job interview.

Comment: "If you need to unload about the bad experience, do it over beers with your friends, not in a job interview." -> The gold nugget in your answer!

Comment: and make sure those friends aren't going to be involved in recruiting you any time soon...

Comment: @jwenting - Or work at the well known company that could add you to a blacklist that might be shared with other IT companies.  The IT industry is smaller then you might think.

Comment: @Ramhound I've worked in IT for going on 20 years, the industry is small but not that small. And I'm less worried about IT professionals as I am about HR flunkies when it comes to such shenanigans, and they're a dime a dozen and will most likely think "hmm, he doesn't want me to hire him, therefore he must be a good candidate".

Comment: @jwenting - Some of the biggest players in the space had illegal agreements not to poach employees from one another.  It wouldn't be unheard of to have a similar list which listed employees that they wouldn't hire.